# When creating jni4.jar file, it shows 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, c#, jni4net

Once I run proxygen and generated clr and jvm file and build.cmd
Then I run build.cmd, but it only create a empty folder named target.
I used command prompt to run the build.cmd, it show "javac is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
[This is the example from command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmZtr.png)

[This is the contents inside the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uc9l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your java file?
But, with this much information it seems like your JAVA_HOME is not set. Also, check your java path must be set. JAVA_HOME needs to be set to your jdk/bin location.